# how to implement forgotten password functionality for password stored in keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, keychain, password-recovery

I am creating a basic iOS app using objective c where the user needs to register  and I am saving the login credentials(username, password and email) in keychain.

I want to give forgot password functionality and was thinking that once the user clicks on forgotten password, I will ask for the user email and match with stored one in keychain and if positive I will send email from the app in background to the user email with password in it.

However I am not sure is this safe and good practice?

I am not using server, so cannot send mail from server.

Or is there any better way to do it. Please suggest?

Comment: what about 'security questions' for forgotten password functionality. you can also store the security questioning & answers in keychain while registering. And user can retrieve their password by answering the security questions.

Comment: It would certainly be better to validate the access in the app and simply show the password than to send the password in the clear, via email.  Validating by email is not very secure, since an attacker presumably has physical access to the phone and therefore has access to the user's email address and email.  Could you perhaps just use the device passcode/TouchID/FaceID?

Comment: thanks @jpulikkottil , seems like lot easier and safe..will try doing this

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for help Paul, so basically validate the information in app and display the password as an alert ?

Comment: Validate the information and ask them for a new password?  Although why not just the local authentication framework and eliminate all of this complexity from your app?

Comment: Hey Thanks @Paulw11 ..I did not knew about this framework, will explore it and try to use it..thanks buddy